# Why does React.StrictMode change component behavior?

Tags: reactjs, frontend, react-table, react-table-v6

I am trying to make react-table select one row at a time. I found some code online which is able to do this: https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-forest-2s48n?file=/src/index.js

While experimenting with this code, I found out that if I removed `<React.StrictMode>` from index.js, the table does multiple row selection. But if I add it back, the table does single-row selection again.

This behavior is confusing because I thought strict mode shouldn't change the component. Why is this the case?

How can I make `react-table` select only one row at a time? I tried wrapping my table component inside of Strict Mode but it's not working.

Comment: I'm unsure why `React.StrictMode` would cause a change in rendering, but I made updates to select a single row at a time: https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-glitter-6btut

Comment: @RossAllen It worked! I would select you as the answer if you answer this question. :)